# taking data from one table view and to display it in another tableview

Tags: iphone

hi i have data in my table view and i just want to display the same data in the next table view , that means (while clicking a button in first view navigating to another view and display the same data in seconds view's table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of considering **taking data from one table to another**, you should think it this way, **the two tables can simply share a common data source (let's say an NSArray)**, even though these two tables have a parent-child hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make two `UITableViews` one in your `firstView` and one in your `secondView` and give them the data from the same source (say it will be an `NSMutableArray` or `NSDictionary`),and you will get the same data in two `UITableViews`.It will be a simple approach and also see [cocoawithlove](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/designing-view-with-bindings.html)